# Why I am getting these different outputs?

Tags: python, string

```
print('xyxxyyzxxy'.lstrip('xyy'))
# output:zxxy

print("xyxefgooeeee".lstrip("efg"))
# ouput:xyxefgooeeee

print('reeeefooeeee'.lstrip('eeee'))
# output:reeeefooeeee
```

Here for the last two print statements, I am expecting output as a first print statement, as it has stripped 'xyxxyy', but in the last two print statements, it is not stripping in the same way as it has done in first. Please tell me why it so?

Comment: `lstrip` is "left strip", it only strips from the left side.

Comment: yes that i know,but my question is why  it did not strip left side characters in the same way as first print statement

Comment: Is your question primarily "why does it behave like that" or "how do I get the behaviour I expected"?

Comment: @Vaibhavi It does strip in exactly the same way. In your second string, the leftmost letter isn’t `'e'`, `'f'` or `'g'`. What do you expect to happen?

Comment: @konard Rudolph I thought I will get this output for second print statement: ooeeee

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`string.lstrip(chars)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.lstrip) removes characters from the left size of the string until it reached a character that does not appear in `chars`.

In your second and third examples, the first character of the string does not appear in `chars`, so no characters are removed from the string.

Answer (score 2):

In Python leading characters in Strings containing xyy are removed because of .lstrip(). For example:

```
txt = ",,,,,ssaaww.....banana"

x = txt.lstrip(",.asw")

print(x)
```

The output will be: banana

Answer (score 0):

I think because the order of char doesn't matter.

`xyy` or `yxx` will result in the same thing. It will remove chars from the left side until it sees a char that is not included. For example:

```
print('xyxxyyzxxy'.lstrip('xyy'))
zxxy

print('xyxxyyzxxy'.lstrip('yxx'))
zxxy
```

In fact, if you only used 2 chars 'xy' or 'yx' you will get the same thing:

```
print('xyxxyyzxxy'.lstrip('xy'))
zxxy
```

In the other cases, the first left char is not included, therefore there's no stripping

Answer (score 0):

I just got to know lstrip() removes, all combinations of the characters passed as an argument are removed from the left-hand side.

Answer (score 0):

lstring using the set of the chars in the string and then removes the all characters from the primary string start from the left

```
print('xyxefgooeeee'.lstrip('yxefg')) 
"""In 'xyxefgooeeee' the first char is 'x' and it exists in the 'yxefg' so 
will be removed and then it will move to the next char 'y','x','x','e','f', 
'g' and then 'o' which doesn't exist. therefore will return string after 'o'
"""
OutPut : ooeeee

print('xyxefgooeeee'.lstrip('efg'))
"""In the xyxefgooeeee' the first char 'x' does to exist in the 'efg' so will
not be removed and will not move to the next char and will return the
entire primary string
"""
OutPut: xyxefgooeeee
```