# Python .rstrip() strips a string even if it doesn't match exactly

Tags: python, strip

```py
print('345nov'.rstrip('nov'))
```

the code above prints what you would expect: `345`

So why does `print('345v'.rstrip('nov'))` print the same thing. The string doesn't end with "nov". It only ends with "v". But `rstrip()` strips it all the same. Either way, how can I make it ignore this behavior and not strip anything unless the ending string matches it exactly.

Comment: Note that this behavior is mentioned in the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.rstrip).

Comment: A dedicated method for that purpose doesn't exist (yet) but there's a discussion on [python-ideas](https://mail.python.org/archives/list/python-ideas@python.org/thread/RJARZSUKCXRJIP42Z2YBBAEN5XA7KEC3/) whether to add one.

Comment: Conceptually a duplicate of [the same question on `lstrip`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58840638/why-i-am-getting-these-different-outputs).

Answer (score 2):

You get this behavior because `rstrip()` actually takes an iterable for its parameter. That means the string you place in ("nov") is interpreted as `['n', 'o', 'v']`. This can be proved further by changing the order of the characters:

```
>>>"345nov".rstrip("nvo")
345
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `endswith` and index the string:

```
string = '345v'
suffix = 'nov'
if string.endswith(suffix):
    string = string[:-len(suffix)]
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing something similar to @a_guest.

```py
def rstrip(a, b):
    if a.endswith(b):
        return a[:-len(b)]
    return a
```

Comment: That's not giving you the correct result, you need to use a negative index.

Comment: It's confusing to name the method `rstrip` when `str.rstrip` does something completely different.